# using yield to make it simpler

Tags: c#, .net, yield

I'm trying to create a list of a class that has nested class in it. Can I somehow use yield in a function to make it shorter and more readeable?

```
var links = new List<UserLink>();

links.Add(new UserLink
    {
        Name = "A",
        Url = "B.com",
        Something = "C",
        Parameters =
            { 
                new Parameter { Name = "X", Value = "Y" }, 
                new Parameter { Name = "Z", ParameterValue = "0" }
            }
    });
```

Comment: What are you trying to shorten? That already looks pretty concise for what it does. In any case, `yield` is used to return an `IEnumerable<T>`. That does not seem to apply here.

Comment: it looks abit messy if I want to add like 5 of those and then do something with the list

Comment: you could always take things as constructor parameters.

Comment: the `yield` keyword won't work here.

Comment: just create UserLink outside before adding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is using constructor, then it will be shorter, though less readable:

```
links.Add(new UserLink("A", "B.com", "C", new Parameter("X", "Y" ), new Parameter("Z", "0")));
```

The last part (passing variable number of Parameter objects) can be achieved by the `params` keyword:

```
public UserLink(string name, string url, string something = "C", params Parameter[] parameters)
{
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Only conceivable way you can use `yield` in this context is:

```
public IEnumerable<UserLink> GetLinks()
{
    yield return new UserLink() { Name = "A", ... };
    yield return new UserLink() { Name = "B", ... };
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**[yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)** is to be used to return IEnumerables, like this:

```
public IEnumerable<UserLink> UserLinks()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        yield return new UserLink
        {
            Name = "A",
            Url = "B.com",
            Something = "C",
            Parameters = 
            { 
                new Parameter { Name = "X", Value = "Y" }, 
                new Parameter { Name = "Z", ParameterValue = i.ToString() }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this, in conjunction with [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx):

```
UserLinks().Where(userlink => userlink.Name == "A")
```